# Can XML have a "double-array" like it has a "string-array"? (Android)

Tags: java, android, xml, arrays

I'm trying to populate a spinner with a dropdown of real numbers. The contents are defined in Java, but in my spinners.xml, the "double-array" is being rejected. Do I have to convert to String to use spinners?

```
 <string-array name="semester_spinner">
    <item>Spring</item>
    <item>Summer</item>
    <item>Fall</item>
    <item>Winter</item>
</string-array>

<double-array name="cred_spinner" />
```

Answer (score 2):

No, Android has no support for a "double-array." It would be nice, considering they already have a string-array and an integer-array.

Are you sure that they need to be double, or could you use Android's built-in [Integer-Array](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#IntegerArray)? If that is not possible, perhaps you could consider using a [Typed-Array](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#TypedArray).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <array name="cred_spinner">
        <item>2.0</item>
        <item>3.0</item>
        <item>4.0</item>
        ...
     </array>
</resources>
```